# How do you cut a beveled curve?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

I'm working on this wing design for future models and I used bevel to create the wing spines. The problem is that the end pokes out at the bottom of the spine. Is there any way to solve this problem? Thanks!
[image: The Arrows point at the bevel of the curve end where I want to get rid of]

Comment: Curve tip geometry is generally controlled by the last curve segement, but you can't really have more granular control over it directly, not without converting to mesh first.

Comment: How would you turn the curve into a mesh?

Comment: @Brian Saehyun Lee ALT-C then select an option